# How can I create cross browser multi range slider?(no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, slider

I've tried to create a **cross browser multi range input slider** (added photo), [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhvwu.png)using only html-css-javascript, but I found it very hard to make it work in browsers such as IE or Edge. is there any way to do it **without** using jQuery or external packeges?

Comment: Those external libraries usually are adding some polyfills to handle differences between browsers maybe research what polyfills do you need or try using modernizer or to check if functionalities are available. You can also try using babel for automatic detecting polyfills.

Comment: Did you see this article https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-range-slider-component-in-react-from-scratch-using-only-div-and-span-d53e1a62c4a3/ ?

Comment: @VahidAl I've looked at it and it's nice but not very good for ux and i need somthing  more user-friendly :)